# MongoDB does not store date accurately while adding new items repeatedly

Tags: mongodb, sorting

If I add new data to MongoDB repeatedly, for example adding 3 data in 2-3 seconds, it stores "createdAt" field same.

I actually does not know much about MongoDB. I don't know what else I should try.

**FactSchema**

```
const FactSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    vote: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now(),
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now(),
    },
});
```

These 3 documents show same createdAt yet they shouldn't be. There should be 2-3 seconds different between them.

```
_id: 5d6a8d6863a5d51af80eec87
createdAt: 2019-08-31T15:08:18.190+00:00
```

```
_id: 5d6a8d6f63a5d51af80eec88
createdAt: 2019-08-31T15:08:18.190+00:00
```

```
_id: 5d6a8d7263a5d51af80eec89
createdAt: 2019-08-31T15:08:18.190+00:00
```

Comment: This is not a MongoDB issue.  It look like a mongoose / point of data expression eval issue.  Are you using mongoose?   I am not a mongoose expert but I suspect `Date.now()` is evaluated only once, when the `Schema` is created.   Unless you explicitly create a new date when you make new docs using this schema as a template and insert them , like you might for `text` and `vote` , then that old, stale date will be used.

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to show some code which reproduces the issue. Note that as stated, this is not a MongoDB issue ( MongoDB does not set the dates, but just inserts what your code tells it to ) but is rather an issue with the implemented code. Show the **minimal** code that reproduces this and someone can point out what is being done incorrectly.

Comment: Also there is no need to set this schema manually. Use the [timestamps](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) schema option instead, which has more detailed code around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Date.now` instead of `Date.now()`.

Update:
Date.now sends the function itself to mongoose which will be evaluated at the time of "document creation", 
Whereas Date.now() is the evaluated value which is created when it is run for the first time, that is, at the time of "schema creation".

Comment: Whats difference between the two?

Comment: Thank you for your nicely explained answer. Works for sure :)